# How to sort a translated date with jQuery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, locale, tablesorter

I want to sort a date column with the JQuery Tablesorter Plugin. I have created my custom parser as my date is not in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format or other accepted formats.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'dayMonthYear',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        let date = s.match(/^(\d{1,2})\s+(\w+)\s+(\d{4})$/);
        let d = date ? date[1] || '' : '';
        let y = date && date[3] ? date[3] || '' : '';
        let m = date && date[2] ? date[2] || '' : '';

        return new Date(d + " " + m + " " + y).getTime() || '';

    },
    type: 'Numeric'
});


$('#leaderBoardTable').tablesorter({
    theme: "default",
    headers: {1: {sorter: 'dayMonthYear'}} //add the custom parser we defined above
});
```

However, our system has multiple translations: NL, FR, JA, RU, ES and 21+ more. This parser only worked for the EN translation. Therefore this parser did not work for the other translations:

```
1 July 2020  (EN) //works
20 juli 2020 (NL) //doesn't work
```

Here is a fiddle showing my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/jLuzqp7r/4/

The bottom table sorts perfectly, while the top doesn't.

Comment: See https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-dates.html